# Linked pictures

Tags: visual, connections-puzzle

Can you find the link in them? The answer should explain the link in all three of them.

[image: Someone is dead]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, on the left, there's a picture of

> apple bobbing, a common event on Halloween,

on the right, there's a picture of

> Indira Gandhi, the only female Prime Minister of India, who was assassinated on Halloween, and

on the bottom, there's a string of characters that

> can be placed at the end of `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=` in order to find [a cricket match between India and Sri Lanka](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UMqZdYXvih4) which happened [on Halloween, 2005](http://www.espncricinfo.com/indvsl/engine/current/match/223634.html)

Comment: never thought it would be too fast... [add it](http://www.espncricinfo.com/indvsl/engine/current/match/223634.html) to your answer...

Comment: thank you - tracking down the date was difficult. I don't know much about cricket, so I was kind of guessing at terminology.

Answer (score 4):

The link is:

> Halloween. The painting is called Snap-Apple Night and depicts Irish folks celebrating on Halloween. The photo is of Indira Ghandi, who was assassinated on Halloween Day.

Comment: lol, what did we answer within a minute of each other?

Comment: +1 but sorry ...the other answer is bit more complete...

Comment: Looks like we did, but you got the complete answer (can't access youtube from work to get the third piece. Cursed filters!)

Comment: @Irishpanda I'm in a similar situation - some stuff (seemingly arbitrary) is blocked, some isn't. This one happened to be not blocked.